# When do functions get .plt entries in GLIBC when there are multiple definitions?

Tags: c, elf, glibc, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Some functions are defined twice across GLIBC libraries. For example, consider `_dl_signal_exception`:

```
$ readelf -s libc-2.31.so | grep _dl_signal_exception
   103: 0000000000138130    77 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _dl_signal_exception@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
$ readelf -s ld-2.31.so | grep _dl_signal_exception
     2: 000000000001a8b0    73 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 _dl_signal_exception@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

Other functions in `ld.so` call `_dl_signal_exception` and thus `_dl_signal_exception` gets a `.plt` entry which at runtime will actually resolve to `libc.so`'s `_dl_signal_exception`. As I understand it, shared libraries (on Linux) will make function calls indirectly (unless static) to support symbol interposition.

However, other functions in `libc.so` call `_dl_signal_exception`, but there is no `.plt` entry in `libc.so` for this function.

So I have two questions:

1. Why does `ld.so` define `_dl_signal_exception` when it can just get it from `libc.so`?
2. Why don't we see a `.plt` entry for `_dl_signal_exception` in `libc.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does ld.so define _dl_signal_exception when it can just get it from libc.so?

The `ld.so` is *special* -- it is what the kernel transfers control to after mapping the main executable and `ld.so` (the path to which is hard-coded into the main executable's `PT_INTERP` segment).

*No other library is present yet* -- it is the job of `ld.so` to load all other libraries.

So `ld.so` *must* be completely stand-alone, and can't depend on any other library (including `libc.so`). Because of this, `ld.so` has its own (smallish) `malloc`, and other parts of `libc` which it needs to `open` and `mmap` files, etc.

> Why don't we see a .plt entry for _dl_signal_exception in libc.so?

A lot of `libc.so` calls are considered internal implementation detail, and bypass the `.plt`. This is achieved using `internal_call` macro in GLIBC sources.

For example, the fact that `fopen` (potentially) uses `mmap` is internal implementation detail, and the call from `fopen` to `mmap` is hidden from interposition.

Comment: Why isn't the call to `_dl_signal_exception` from `ld.so` also hidden from interposition? Shouldn't this also be considered an internal implementation detail?

Comment: @peachykeen I don't know. Maybe it must be exported because the `libc.so` one will call it, or it could be an oversight, or there is some other reason.